# How to list data from database using orderby type and daywise in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating commercial website.my website contain post ads form.That forms contain ad type field. That have 3 types: Deluxe,Premium,Regular. I have posted 10 records using ads forms. Now , I want list my ads data using order by ad type - deluxe(5-day wise), premium(5-day wise)....), all regular(day wise)

Answer (score 0):

Simply invoke `orderBy()` as many times as you need it. For instance:

```
User::orderBy('type', 'DESC')
->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I want to use conditions in order by .

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the condition your are use.

Comment: $ads = Advertisement::where('ad_status',1)

 ->orderByRaw('case 
when ads_type LIKE "%Deluxe%" then 1 
when ads_type LIKE "%Premium%" then 2 
when ads_type LIKE "%Regular%" then 3 
 end')->get();

Comment: Use this code `$ads = Advertisement::where('ad_status',1)
        ->where('ads_type', 'LIKE', '%Deluxe%')
        ->where('ads_type', 'LIKE', '%Premium%')
        ->where('ads_type', 'LIKE', '%Regular%')
        ->orderBy('ads_type')
        ->get();`

Comment: i have one question. i want show deluxe is first then deluxe else premium next.and premium else regular so i am using $ads = Advertisement::where('ad_status',1)

 ->orderByRaw('case 
when ads_type LIKE "%Deluxe%" then 1 
when ads_type LIKE "%Premium%" then 2 
when ads_type LIKE "%Regular%" then 3 
 end')->get(); its work perfect to me.now i want delex type ads only shown from posted date to 5 day only then that ads change to regular.

Comment: Use this query `$ads = DB::table('Advertisement')->where('ads_type', 'LIKE', '%Regular%')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ads = Advertisement::where('ad_status',1)

 ->orderByRaw('case 
when ads_type LIKE "%Deluxe%" then 1 
when ads_type LIKE "%Premium%" then 2 
when ads_type LIKE "%Regular%" then 3 
 end')->get();
```